# How to get focus at 0th position always in HorizontalGridView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tv, leanback

I am creating android tv application and requirement is inside horizontal grid view i have many card views. I want that all my cards get focused at 0 position of horizontal gridview. That is when I click right button on remote cards should get shift to left so that my card shows the focused position at 0 always.

Comment: you can use requestFocus() for 0th index. row of grid view.

Answer (score 0):

For focus you need to add below line when click to button

```
yourView.requestFocus();
```

Or

```
smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.